# SQL PIVOT: One To Many

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have 2 table in SQL.

dbo.main

```
|id | mid | tid 
 1    yes    no
```

dbo.external

```
| id | type | element |
  1    c        9
  1    d        10
  1    h        11
  1    g        12
```

What i try to achieve is :

```
| id | mid | tid | c | d | h | g  |
  1    yes    no   9  10  11   12
```

i try to use pivot on dbo.external statment as

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT id,type,element
  FROM dbo.external
) SRC
PIVOT
(
  MAX(FIELD_DATA)
  FOR FIELD_NUMBER IN (id,type,element)
) PIV;
```

The problem is: 
 how can i pivot dbo.external  then join the dbo.main in one sql statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `JOIN` the `Main` table in `Pivot` source query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT e.id,mid,tid,[element],[type] 
        FROM   dbo.[external] e 
               JOIN main m 
                 ON e.id = m.id) a 
       PIVOT ( Max([element]) 
             FOR [type] IN ([c],[d],[h],[g]) ) PIV
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71259/1)

Answer (score 4):

Use `WITH` clause:

```
WITH temp AS(
   -- here make the join
)
SELECT id,mid,tid, c,d,h,g
FROM temp
PIVOT
(
  MAX(FIELD_DATA)
  FOR type IN (c,d,h,g)
) as PIV;
```